# R: Fixing my gwidget window size

Tags: r, gwidgets

So i have done an entire gwidget script which creates the GUI for running my scripts .

```
    win <- gwindow("TITLE HERE",height=500,weight=500)
```

However it seems that whenever i maximize the window, or elongate the window size by dragging it, it breaks and the size doesn't fix anymore.

Any idea how to force the window to not be able to resize ? or a permanent way to fix the size.

Here is an image of my situation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R92Hn.jpg

I'm also using gwidgets and gwidgetscltk package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is not possible using `gwidgets`. You can set andle a "resize event or signal".

One alternative is to use `RGtk2` (GTK+ 2.0):

```
library(RGtk2)
win <- gtkWindow("toplevel", show = FALSE)
gtkWidgetSetSizeRequest(win, 500, 500)
win$show()
gtkWindowSetResizable(win, FALSE)
```

Comment: Yup, that's right. The user would also need something similar using Tk commands if using gWidgetstcltk.